# Concurrent stack implementation using MVar

Tags: haskell, concurrency

I am trying to implement a stack for use in a concurrent application. I would like the following semantics: `push` should never block, and `pop` should block the calling thread on an empty stack, but still permit `push`es. I implemented it as follows (irrelevant bits at the bottom):

```
data Stream a = Stream a (MVar (Stream a))
data Stack a = Stack (MVar (Int, MVar (Stream a)))

popStack :: Stack a -> IO a 
popStack (Stack stack) = do 
  (sz, mvar) <- takeMVar stack
  mbStream <- tryTakeMVar mvar 
  case mbStream of 
    Nothing -> putMVar stack (sz, mvar) >> popStack (Stack stack)
    Just (Stream x xs) -> putMVar stack (sz-1, xs) >> return x
```

If the stream `MVar` is empty I have to release the lock on the stack and try again. However, this seems like a kludge: if a thread calls `pop` on an empty stack, it could loop several times before being suspended, even though the `MVar` will not become full while that thread is being executed. Is there a better way utilizing `MVar`s to write `pop` with the desired semantics?

---

```
import Control.Concurrent.MVar 
import Control.Monad 
import Control.Concurrent
import Text.Printf

newStack :: IO (Stack a) 
newStack = do 
  stream <- newEmptyMVar 
  Stack <$> newMVar (0, stream)

pushStack :: Stack a -> a -> IO ()
pushStack (Stack stack) val = do 
  (sz, stream) <- takeMVar stack
  stream' <- newMVar (Stream val stream)
  putMVar stack (sz+1, stream')

test = do 
  s <- newStack
  _ <- forkIO $ mapM_ (\a -> printf "pushing %c... " a >> pushStack s a >> threadDelay 100000) ['a' .. 'z']
  _ <- forkIO $ do 
         replicateM 13 (popStack s) >>= printf "\npopped 13 elems: %s\n"
         replicateM 13 (popStack s) >>= printf "\npopped 13 elems: %s\n"
  threadDelay (5*10^6)
  putStrLn "Done"
```

Comment: The given semantics is incomplete. You need something like "each pop result had been pushed". Still, you cannot distinguish a stack from a queue (?), so you could look at (the source code of) http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Control-Concurrent-Chan.html . Note that there's no `tryTakeMVar` in there. And - do you absolutely want to do the locking on your own? If not, consider STM.

Comment: @d8d0d65b3f7cf42 Why do I need to add that to the semantics? If a value is popped, how else could it have arrived there if it weren't pushed? Chan is FIFO, Stack is the opposite (LIFO) - how are they indistinguishable? It would be great if I could write `Stack` in terms of `Chan`. I've seen `Chan`, I don't think I can implement `Stack` the same way - for Stack the read and write MVars would point to the same value anyways. I could use STM - but would that solve this particular problem?

Comment: Your spec only speaks about blocking. You need to add something about values. Otherwise your implementation could manufacture then out of thin air, or ignore something that's been pushed, or duplicate it. It is not obvious what FIFO should mean in a concurrent setting. Perhaps you want some quiescent property ("if only one thread is running, then it's FIFO"), or linearizability. All of this needs to be stated explicitly before we can start talking about (correcntess of) an implementation.

Comment: OK, I see what you mean when you say the semantics are incomplete. push should always increase the number of elements on the stack by 1, and pop should always reduce that number by 1, unless the stack is empty, in which case it blocks. I would that if I know 1 was pushed before 2, this implies that 2 will be popped before 1. In any case, I will read the paper you linked before proceeding.

Comment: you don't necessarily have a well-defined "before" relation, or you would need too much locking to enforce it.

Comment: @user2407038 what you mean is probably "linearizable with respect to FILO semantics", which just means more or less that when operations overlap you can always say e.g. "okay, the push *really* happened at this moment (between the time when `push` was called and when it returned), and the pop happened at this moment, and that matches my simple intuition about how this should behave". In other words there's always some possible/imagined interleaving of any set of operations which is correct w/r/t your semantics. d8d0d65b3f7cf42 is being a bit pedantic, IMHO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick critique:

1. "push should never block" is not something you are going to actually achieve.  Though you may have a perdonal definition of "block" that is different than the GHC meaning.  For instance, your pushStack does block.
2. popStack on an empty stack goes into a very busy loop, repeatedly taking and putting the Stack MVar.  You do not want to do this, you even say "pop should block".
3. You use takeMVar and putMVar instead of withMVar or modifyMVar.  This means you are not thinking about exceptions, and the Stack will not be good in a general library.

So you have learned about MVars, and you are using them with them to learn more.

Here StackData is either a stack with data (Full) or without data (Empty).  When Empty, there is an initally empty MVar for hungry poppers to wait upon.

```
type Lock = MVar ()
type Some a = (a, [a]) -- non empty version of list
data StackData a = Full !(Some a)
                 | Empty !Lock
data Stack a = Stack { stack :: MVar (StackData a) }

pop s = do
    x <- modifyMVar (stack s) $ \ sd ->
           case sd of
               Empty lock -> do
                   return (Empty lock, Left lock)
               Full (a, []) -> do
                   lock <- newEmptyMVar
                   return (Empty lock, Right a)
               Full (a, (b:bs)) -> return (Full (b, bs), Right a)
    case x of
        Left lock -> do
            withMVar lock return  -- wait on next pusher
            pop s
        Right a -> return a


 push s a = modifyMVar_ (stack s) $ \ sd ->
           case sd of
               Empty lock -> do
                   tryPutMVar lock () -- should succeed, releases waiting poppers
                   evaluate Full (a,[]) -- do not accumulate lazy thunks
               Full (b, bs) -> do
                   xs <- evaluate (b:bs) -- do not accumulate lazy thunks
                   evaluate (Full (a, xs)) -- do not accumulate lazy thunks
```

Note : I have not tried to compile this.

EDIT: A safer version of push needs to only put () into the lock when it has succeeded in modifying the stack from Empty to Full.  This certainty can be achieved with the 'mask' operation.  The 'restore' is used inside 'modifyMVar' but is not required:

```
push s a = mask $ \restore -> do
    mLock <- modifyMVar (stack s) $ \ sd -> restore $
           case sd of
               Empty lock -> do
                   n <- evaluate Full (a,[]) -- do not accumulate lazy thunks
                   return (n, Just lock)
               Full (b, bs) -> do
                   xs <- evaluate (b:bs) -- do not accumulate lazy thunks
                   n <- evaluate (Full (a, xs))
                   return (n, Nothing)
    whenJust mLock $ \ lock -> tryPutMVar lock ()
```

Comment: 1. It blocks but only if there is another push, and pushes should happen quickly so in practice it should (I hope) behave as if it doesn't block. 2. That is the point of the question. 3. I planned to implement exception handling later. I wanted to get the basics working first.

Comment: Your implementation seems to do what I want. But why evaluate the entire stack on a push? I want things to be evaluated by poppers, not pushers.

Comment: Our pushers and poppers both takeMVar stack and so block additional users.  The evaluate is only WHNF, forcing just the new (:)-cons cell and the Full-constructor. The data itself is not forced.  This prevents pushers building a long chain of unforced (:) and Full applications.  Making data types with a strict (!) constructors would also make it WHNF.  Putting lazy things into MVars without forcing properly is a common glitch, so I avoided making a bad example.  If a blocker popper dies, or is killed while popping, then no element of the stack is lost; a pusher dying is safer with new edit.

Answer (score 2):

It's not very exciting, but the simplest solution would be to use [`STM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm-2.4.3/docs/Control-Monad-STM.html) (if you're using cabal you'll need the `stm` package in your dependencies list).

```
import Control.Concurrent.STM

newtype Stack a = Stack (TVar [a])

new :: STM (Stack a)
new = fmap Stack $ newTVar []

put :: a -> Stack a -> STM ()
put a (Stack v) = modifyTVar' v (a:)

get :: Stack a -> STM a
get (Stack v) = do
    stack <- readTVar v
    case stack of
         [] -> retry
         (a:as) -> do writeTVar v as
                      return a
```

You get the blocking behavior you want with `retry`, which is implemented in such a way that threads won't be awoken until the `TVar` changes to something other than `[]`. This is also nice because you can now use your stack in larger composed atomic transactions, and you don't have to worry about making sure exceptions don't break your structure.

If you're trying to do high-performance concurrency with lots of threads contending for reads and/or writes, you might find that this isn't clever enough. In that case you might have fun designing a structure based around the `fetch-and-add`-based counter from [atomic-primops](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/atomic-primops-0.6.0.5/docs/Data-Atomics-Counter.html), or seeing what else is available on hackage.

Comment: Cf. Hendler, Shavit, Yerushalmi: A Scalable Lock-free Stack Algorithm (Sect. 5) (16th ACM Symp. on Parallelism in Algorithms and Architectures) http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~hendlerd/papers/scalable-stack.pdf